# Changing Text Color in Finder on Mojave Dark Mode?

Tags: finder, mojave, color

I recently switched over to Dark Mode, and for visual symmetry, I made my Finder window backgrounds dark grey (so that I don't have a black window with a white filled-in background. However, this makes the text quite hard to read -- is there any way to change (or simply invert) the text color for icon labels in Finder?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try toggling it again; it should relaunch Finder with a fully dark theme, including dark backgrounds & white text...

[image]

Comment: So, I've got that -- for almost all the folders in my Finder, this works. However, my "Recents" folder, and that folder alone, will not allow me to set the background color to "Default", and retains the dark text color even when I change its background to be dark. Weird.
Thanks though! Finder working for all but 1 location is pretty good :)

Comment: Nearly there! ;) Perhaps it's a fix in 10.14.1 which I currently am using in beta. I can't repro the issue, but something seems to have got 'stuck' somewhere...